# Why 'sudo' doesn't ask for password?

Tags: command-line

When I type 'sudo' before command to act as a superuser, it never ask me for the password at all.
I didn't remember what I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your sudoers privilege. Sometimes permission might be over written. Do the follow:

```
cd /etc/sudoers.d
sudo visudo
```

I will assume you will have

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Change it to

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Hope it help :)

Comment: How I can save changes with visudo after editing? My Ubuntu is 14.04LTS.

Comment: exit the editing mode (esc) then type :x or :wq (then enter)

Comment: It also not work, I can't exit from editing mode, it's not like vi editor

Comment: It's working fine for me!

Comment: It  only works with pressing Ctrl+Shift+x

Comment: So, mine is `# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
`

And it doesn't prompt for a password. Is there something else causing that here?

Answer (score 2):

During a single session, `sudo` may only ask for your password the first time you use sudo.

Use

```
sudo -K
```

when you are done using sudo to revoke that status.

Comment: Even I make restart it still doesn't ask me for password

Comment: Aah yes, I see that NOPASSWD was probably the culprit. BTW, it is possible to edit the sudoers file with vi, nano, gedit, or whatever but it not recommended because syntax errors will not be fixed and you might be left without the needed sudo privilege to fix it.